# Tesseract doesn't fetch data clearly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

- In this Python script, First I increase the image Resolution for better accuracy of OCR.
- Second, I apply many filters to that image to increase contrast and text clarity.
- Third, I fetch text from filtered image using Tesseract But **the issue is Tesseract doesn't fetch data clearly**.
- And also tried to add page segmentation modes and OCR Engine modes on the pytesseract but did not receive the expected output.
- This is my Code...

```
import os,argparse  
import pytesseract  
from pytesseract import Output  
import csv  
import numpy as np  
from PIL import Image  

image = cv2.imread('dota.jpg')

height = 9000
width = 16000

dimensions = (width, height)

image = cv2.resize(image,dimensions, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)  
def get_grayscale(image):  
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
def adaptiveThreshold(image):  
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
gray = get_grayscale(image)
sharpenKernel = np.array(([[2, -1, 2], [-1, 9, -1], [2, -1, 2]]), np.float32)/9
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(src=gray, kernel=sharpenKernel, ddepth=-1)
adthresh = adaptiveThreshold(sharpen)
cong = '--psm 6'  
final = pytesseract.image_to_data(adthresh,output_type=Output.DICT,config=cong,lang='eng')  
print(final['text'])
```

- Also, this code is available on Github.
  : https://github.com/Bhavin-Prydan/Dota-Esportz/blob/main/dota.py

Comment: what images are you trying it on?

Comment: Dota's scoreboard (PC game) Image

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I have Solved my problem with Paddle-OCR

Comment: It would be great if you can post the answer

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting Tesseract OCR jobs, it's handy to run a loop through each of the Page Segmentation Modes, since the modes are optimized for different kinds of input.    This means that Tesseract can produce dramatically superior/inferior results just because the right/wrong PSM is being used.

A function like this, for example, will let you try different PSMs and also test the effect of some basic image pre-processing.

```
from PIL import Image as pillowImageLoader
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

def testTesseract(someFilename, psmValue=3, processABit=True):
    if processABit:
        img = np.array(pillowImageLoader.open(someFilename))
        norm_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
        img = cv2.normalize(img, norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (1, 1), 0)
    try:
        someText = pytesseract.image_to_string(someFilename, config='--psm {}'.format(psmValue))
        return someText
    except:
        return None
```

Then run through each psm and check your output:

```
for i in range(1,14):
    someText = testTesseract(imageFilename, i, processABit=True)
    print("PSM: {}".format(i))
    print(someText
    print("="*40)
```

I typically use Tesseract on scanned text (documents), but I find it's not as good at finding text in images (e.g. reading the text of a road sign from a photograph, or pulling text out of a screen capture)

I find that PaddleOCR is typically much better at the most challenging OCR tasks, and is quite easy to use:

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en',use_gpu=False)
result = ocr.ocr(imageFilename, cls=True)
print("Paddle Found: {} text segments".format(len(result[0])))
print()
for t in result[0]:
        print("{}  (Conf: {:.1%})".format(t[1][0], t[1][1]))
```